# NSWindowController and NSViewController

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nswindow, nswindowcontroller, nsviewcontroller

Probably a pretty simple question, but I can't get my head around it.

I would like to create some sort of wizard: An `NSWindow` appears as a sheet from another `NSWindow` and should show three different `NSView`s one after another.

I think I should create a custom `NSWindowController` and three `NSViewController`s but I don't know how to how to set up the controllers and how to exchange the views.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In a nutshell, your window controller would instantiate the three view controllers, have a host view, and add `-[NSView addSubview:]` or remove `-[NSView removeFromSuperView]` the view controllers’ views as subviews of the host view. Depending on how you structure your code, you can also use `-[NSView replaceSubview:with:]` to replace a subview with another one.

Apple’s [View Controller sample code](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/ViewController/) features view switching using view controllers.

Comment: I just noticed the `contentView` of a `NSWindow`. Are there any reasons not to use it?

Comment: @fabian789 You could use `contentView` as the host view. However, if you decide to place other controls in your window besides the subviews, having the host view be a subview of `contentView` makes things easier since you wouldn’t have to change the code that swaps the subviews.

Answer (score 0):

@Bavarious asnwer is good, folks like me always need a good snippet of code:

```
appDelegate = (AppDelegate*)[[NSApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
self.masterViewController = [[MasterViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MasterViewController" bundle:nil];
[appDelegate.window.contentView replaceSubview:self.view with:self.masterViewController.view];
```

I create the `appDelegate` object because it is being called from an `NSViewController` otherwise you can get the view from self.

Comment: @nitinkachhadiya thats what I do In my mac apps, it works great for me

Comment: not working but what happens, any errors, any crash. You are doing something wrong because this code has been tested

Comment: home=[[RegistrationViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"RegistrationViewController" bundle:nil];
    [home.view setWantsLayer:YES];
    home.view.layer.backgroundColor=NSColorFromRGBWithAlpha(0xcc4941,1.0).CGColor;
    home.view.frame = self.view.bounds;
    [appDelegate.window.contentView replaceSubview:self.view with:home.view];

Comment: appDelegate had no window property!

Comment: The first line alone was enough for me to get moving.  I didn't realize that you could get a singleton for the AppDelegate like this.

Comment: Does not, the sharedApplication.delegate does not have window property, I recommend use mainWindow or keyWindow as the case may be.